# Can you use the Discord API to get what servers the bot is in, and How?

Tags: discord

Im trying to make a discord dashboard all out of **Pure HTML** *(Includes JS, CSS just to be clear)*, and I wanted to get a list of all the guilds the bot is in **without any other APIs like discord.py or discord.js**.
How can I do this? I couldn't find **anything** on the **Discord Developer Documentation**, and is it even possible?

I've tried some answers like getting **'/users/@me/guilds'**, but it just returns the current person that is logged in with the bot's guilds, and not what the bot has joined.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make an HTTP requests with your bot's token:

```
URL: https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me/guilds
HEADERS: Authorization: "Bot TOKEN"
```

It will return a JSON with all the guilds your bot is in.
But make sure you don't leak your bot's token somewhere in JS or HTML files.
I guess this should work, have a good day! :D

Comment: I found the difference between getting the users's guilds method's headings is 'Bearer Access Token' and other answers don't say to use 'BOT bot token' for getting the bot's guilds, so thanks for clarifying :)